# What's the visibility of a class by default in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, visibility

I could find the default visibility of a property and a method in the [PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). But i couldn't find any info regarding the class itself.

My guess is that it's public. But if someone could link to the part where this is written in the manual i would appreciate it.

Comment: PHP doesn't support anything other than public classes

Comment: Your guess is correct for default methods modifiers, they are public methods(php4 compatibility). But omitting of access modifier will generate a notice. About class itself - all classes are always public.

Comment: My experience is mostly focused in PHP so I need to ask: how does class visibility work exactly in languages that support it? Is it related to inheritance?

Comment: PHP has no concept of packages (namespaces are somewhat similar but not the same) to the concept of class visibility has no meaning in PHP.  They're effectively always public

Comment: While in PHP, classes are generally always public; there is now one exception to that in PHP 7... "Anonymous Classes", classes whose definition and instantiation are always directly under the control of your code, and can thus be used as private classes

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález If I write a class library in PHP, then everybody using that library has direct access to instantiate any class that exists in that library, however and whenever they wish; which may not always be a good idea. Non-public classes would allow me to define classes that could only be instantiated from within my library itself, reducing the potential for problems cause by direct access in external code

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález In Java, classes, which are not explicitly declared as `public`, can only be used by classes in the same package (think `namespace` in PHP). In C#, classes, which are not explicitly declared as `public` are considered `internal` by default, which means they can only be used by classes within the same assembly (I don't think there's a corresponding concept in PHP). "Be used" includes inheritance, among other things. Overall, class visibility is a nice feature, since it allows to hide classes, which are an implementation detail, improving the encapsulation of a program module.

Comment: In addition to the concept of anonymous classes added to PHP 7, as mentioned by @MarkBaker, there is also [an active RFC proposing the addition of a class friendship concept to the language](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/friend-classes). As I write, this RFC is still marked as under discussion and thus won't be in the forthcoming PHP 7.1 release even though the patch has been written, but it could be added to future versions.

Comment: @iainn post your comment as an answer please. I think that your comment answers my question perfectly. And you were the first one to answer, so i think that the credit should go to you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Simply Put

**Public**. PHP doesn't support anything other than public classes.

Unlike Java/.NET/etc, there isn't any concept of packages, assemblies, internal or nested classes. Namespaces are essentially just syntactic sugar to avoid IncrediblyLongClassNames, and can't provide any actual changes to visibility.

The entire idea makes much less sense in a non-compiled language, since regardless of what scope you use, anyone could still just take your class and declare it in public.

## A PHP 7 Proviso: Anonymous Classes

PHP 7 introduced the concept of [anonymous classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php)*, allowing on-the-fly class definitions. As a very basic example:

```
<?php
$foo = new class {
    public function hello($what)
    {
        echo 'Hello ', $what, PHP_EOL;
    }
};

(new $foo)->hello('world');

# Hello world
```

Because these can be assigned to variables, they can be limited to the scope of that variable, and passed around like any other.

Unlike most language that allow anonymous classes, in PHP they do **not** inherit anything from the scope in which they are defined. The linked documentation has some examples of how to work around this, by defining the anonymous class as inheriting from a parent or passing in constructor arguments.

<sub>*Strictly speaking, under the hood they do have names, and as such if someone can run `get_class()` on an instance then they can then instantiate their own copy, since [they aren't garbage collected](https://3v4l.org/n7YdT).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

PHP are always public "by default", but the most accurate answer here is that PHP classes don't have such concept anyway.