# PHP Private or Hidden Class

Tags: php

I am trying to only allow access to certain php classes within certain namespaces. Is there a way or work-around to make php classes only visible or accessible within a namespace kind of like C#’s internal scope?

Comment: Nope, PHP doesn't support anything other than public classes. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455380/whats-the-visibility-of-a-class-by-default-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, you can't have nested classes.

You can use namespaces and private members.

```
// Root namespace
namespace MyParentClass 
{
  use MyParentClass\PrivateClass\PrivateNode;

  class Node
  {
    private $privateClass;

    public function getPrivateClass()
    {
      if (!isset($this->privateClass)) {
        $this->privateClass = new PrivateNode();
      }

      return $this->privateClass;
    }
  }
}

// Pseudo scope
namespace MyParentClass\PrivateClass
{
  class PrivateNode
  {
    private $name = 'PrivateNode';

    public function getName()
    {
      return $this->name;
    }
  }
}

// Test script
namespace
{
  $node = new MyParentClass\Node();

  echo $node->getPrivateClass()->getName();
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Note: Daniel put a link to anonymous classes which can be another interesting way.